# How to pass total value in CrossTab rows (Crystal Report)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I have the following tables in my data:

[image]

How do I create a crosstab report reflecting the total amount of loans of book titles for each month? Like so:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Sorry how do I do that?

Comment: @mukeshkudi It's a self contained issue in a Crystal Report, there's no code snippet to show.